# Replacing HTTP_GET_VARS but with what?

Tags: php, http, variables, get

I am working on legacy code, updating it.

This is part of a form for deleting a number of entries a one time.

After the form is submitted this is the code:

```
else{

//$msgcheck = db_query("DELETE FROM Comments WHERE ID = '$thisid'");


while( $xvar = each( $HTTP_GET_VARS ) )
{
            //print $HTTP_GET_VARS[$myvarname];
            $myqrystr = "DELETE FROM Comments WHERE ID = '" . $xvar["value"] . "'";
            $msgcheck = db_query($myqrystr);
}
```

What I don't get is how does this work? As you can see from the commented code the variable is $thisid - but how does the subsequent code know this from HTTP_GET_VARS? I know I should use $_GET instead, but where does the variable come in?

Comment: What does _"how does the subsequent code know this from HTTP_GET_VARS?"_ mean? Why should the code "know" where a variable comes from?

Answer (score 2):

First, this is higly insecure code, you have a nice SQL injection inside.

This code goes through the `$HTTP_GET_VARS` array and run a delete query for each available argument, you could do the same with `$_GET`, but looping on each argument is really a bad practice.
Here I think one of the query string argument should be an array, with a value key (something like `?foo[value]=42` in the request) and this argument will make the delete-42-query other arguments, which are not arrays, will generate notices (or warnings) and end up as `DELETE FROM Comments WHERE ID = ''` which do not delete anything.

So first, check what query are really made to this function (find the name of the `foo` argument.

The SQL injection here could be something like that:

- `?foo[value]=' or '1'='1` : deleting every row
- `?foo[value]='; DROP table user where '1'='1`
- ...

Finally code should be something like that:

If you have numeric identifiers (which is always better):

```
$arg = $_GET['foo'];
$id = (int) $arg['value']; //<--- no more injection
$myqrystr = "DELETE FROM Comments WHERE ID = " . $id ;
$msgcheck = db_query($myqrystr);
```

If you do not have numeric identifiers, you'll need to add this id as a query argument. I see db_query, there's maybe a way to add arguments to this function, depends on the library, if it is drupal it would be something like:

```
$arg = $_GET['foo'];
$id = $arg['value'];
$myqrystr = "DELETE FROM Comments WHERE ID = :id";
$dbargs = array(':id' => $id)
$msgcheck = db_query($myqrystr, $dbargs);
```

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is automatically populated with all the GET parameters.

If you call that URL:

```
test.php?param1=test&param2=ok&ert=true
```

you will get this variables:

```
$_GET['param1'] == 'test'
$_GET['param2'] == 'ok'
$_GET['ert'] == 'true'
```

$_GET is a superglobal: this array is available is any section of your script (function, main, class, etc.)

Comment: Ok, but if I change it to this it still doesn't work: while( $xvar = each( $_GET ) )

Answer (score 0):

$_GET
$_POST
and other superglobals are always available in php:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php